# Search window not opening in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.5, search-window

I can no longer search for tools, etc using the Search window in ArcMap i.e. Windows | Search doesn't work and nor does <kbd>ctrl + f</kbd>.

I thought updating my student license would do the trick but after doing so it's still the same. I have also tried to fix it by deleting Normal.mxt but that didn't work either.

I read somewhere that ArcMap can sometimes misbehave because of problems related to the pc user account.

I may accidentally have shut down my computer the wrong way last week and before I was properly logged off (by pulling the plug too early).

What could be the cause of this and how may I fix it?

My version of ArcMap is 10.5.0.6491.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS?  Which search has disappeared - the Find button to find records in layers in your map, or the Search window to find tools and datasets?  The Search Window can be re-added by Windows menu > Search

Comment: It sounds more like Find but it would be nice to be sure before spending time writing an answer.

Comment: I have now updated the question. I'm asking about the search tool and no it can not be re-added from the Windows menu.

Comment: The two things that I would try are to first delete your `Normal.mxt` (how to do this is described in other Q&As here), and if that does not fix it then, as an expedient, I would suggest uninstalling and reinstalling ArcGIS Desktop.  Please heed my advice and take the 2-minute [Tour] that is designed to introduce all users to this site and its protocols.  You need to get into the habit of editing your question in response to requests for clarification rather than adding to a comment trail.

Comment: I will do that, and I will not add to this comment trail any further. Maybe you can change the status of the question (it's still closed). Deleting Normal.mxt didn't work.

Comment: Although it may take up to about an hour to uninstall/reinstall ArcGIS Desktop, I find that is often the expedient to resolving what may have gone astray with ArcGIS Desktop on your machine, rather than spending time trying to figure out something that may be very hard to trace.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Have you contacted ESRI's support?

Comment: What OS Version are you using?

Comment: Win 7 professional

Comment: Did you try the usual tech support approach of renaming your ESRI application data folder to see if that fixed it?  It would be something like C:\Users\xxyourusernameherexxx\AppData\Roaming\ESRI?
  A less radical approach would be to just rename your Normal.mxt which would be in the subfolder \Desktop10.5\ArcMap\Templates.  If that doesn't fix things you can rename them back to keep any customizations, and move on to other methods.  Another similar  tech support suggestion would be to rename your ESRI folder in the registry but messing with the registry may not be to your liking.

Comment: Have you uninstalled/reinstalled?  Often that can be the expedient to odd symptoms like this?

Comment: I have a similar issue with the search window. I even reinstalled to no avail.

Comment: is there any chance that reinstallation helps when repair installation did not?

Comment: I have ArcMap 10.5.1 and have no Search Tools functions. Creating a new Windows user seems like a pretty unreasonable solution. Has anyone found a proper fix for this? PS. I deleted both Default_Domain_Path folders from my user ESRI directory and that did not help.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/148550)

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem with Desktop ArcMap 10.6 on Windows 7. I tried the following:

1. Remove `normal.mxt` from the `c:\drive`.
2. Renamed the ESRI folder in the `c:\drive` (essentially the same as step 1, I know.)
3. Deleted `DefaultDomain_Path_folder` from the `c:\drive`.

Option 3 worked for me!

I did not try to create a new user so can not comment on the efficacity of that option.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same problem since 2016.

I contacted ESRI and they sent me different types of possible solutions.

I tried the first solution they emailed me, that is by creating a new Windows user for the computer.

I created a new user and logged out from the current user. When I open ArcMap, the search windows finally appear and everything is functioning normally.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a new user in Windows and log in and Open Arcmap with the new user.

OR

- Remove normal.mxt from this directory
  C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.5\ArcMap\Templates

Comment: Option 2 worked very well.  For those of us that do not have Admin privileges to create a new user this is an easier solution.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted DefaultDomain_Path_  folder from this location C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\ESRI and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently encountered similar problem in ArcGIS 10.5. I applied many possible solutions including renaming 'CATID' folder. However, it didn't worked for me. Alternatively, I logged off to new user account and found 'Search Tool' working properly.

You may copy your data from existing user account, create new windows user account and delete the existing one (optionally). The Search tool would become alive by clicking 'Search tool' button in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 0):

Review the user file inside the DefaultDomain_Path_ folder of this location :

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\ESRI
```

When opened the file showed strange characters (I guess it got corrupted).

What I did was copy a user file from another account and copy it by deleting the corrupt file.